# How to reuse the value retrieved by 2 identical subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

I have prepared a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0cc4a/9) for my question.

In PostgreSQL 10 there are 2 tables holding user ids and user social network data (like given name, photos):

```
CREATE TABLE words_users (
        uid     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE words_social (
        sid     text     NOT NULL,
        social  integer  NOT NULL CHECK (0 < social AND social <= 64),
        given   text     NOT NULL CHECK (given ~ '\S'),
        uid     integer  NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
        PRIMARY KEY(sid, social)
);
```

And there are 2 tables holding games and chat messages:

```
CREATE TABLE words_games (
        gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        player1 integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL CHECK (player1 <> player2),
        player2 integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE words_chat (
        cid     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        created timestamptz NOT NULL,
        gid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_games ON DELETE CASCADE,
        uid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
        msg     text    NOT NULL
);
```

Here I fill the tables with test data:

- User "Alice" with uid=1 and sid="1111" on Facebook (social=10)
- User "Bob" with uid=2 and sid="2222" on Google (social=20)
- Game with with gid=100 where the both users have a chat

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO words_users (uid) VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO words_games (gid, player1, player2) VALUES (100, 1, 2);

INSERT INTO words_social (sid, social, given, uid) VALUES 
('1111', 10, 'Alice', 1), 
('2222', 20, 'Bob', 2);

INSERT INTO words_chat (created, gid, uid, msg) VALUES 
(now() + interval '1 min', 100, 2, 'Hello, Alice'), 
(now() + interval '2 min', 100, 1, 'Hello, Bob'), 
(now() + interval '3 min', 100, 2, 'Nice to see you, Alice'), 
(now() + interval '4 min', 100, 1, 'Nice to see you too, Bob'), 
(now() + interval '5 min', 100, 2, 'Goodbye, Alice'), 
(now() + interval '6 min', 100, 1, 'Goodbye, Bob');
```

I am trying to create a PHP script, which when given the **sid**, **social** and **gid** would return the complete chat for the game gid.

I don't just use **gid** parameter only to fetch and display the chat, because I do not want other users to spy on the games they are not playing.

Also I can not use **uid** paramter to identify the user calling my script, I have to use the **sid** and **social** parameters instead (plus a secret, which I omitted from the above test case).

So here is my SQL-statement to fetch the chat:

```
SELECT uid, msg 
FROM words_chat 
WHERE gid=100 
AND EXISTS (select 1 from words_games where 
   (select uid from words_social 
   where sid='1111' and social=10) in (player1, player2)) 
ORDER BY CREATED ASC;
```

[image: screenshot]

It works, but I need 1 more thing, which makes it complicated - for each chat **msg** I need a boolean (instead of the **uid**) to know if that is a message by "Alice" or not (so that I can draw that line in bold font).

So I am trying to do this and the SQL statement gets even uglier:

```
SELECT uid=(select uid from words_social 
   where sid='1111' and social=10) AS mine, msg 
FROM words_chat 
WHERE gid=100 
AND EXISTS (select 1 from words_games where 
   (select uid from words_social 
   where sid='1111' and social=10) in (player1, player2)) 
ORDER BY CREATED ASC;
```

[image: screenshot 2]

As you see in the above screenshot this works, but how to improve this query?

Is there a way in SQL (i.e. I would prefer not to save the **uid** value in my PHP script or to use pl/pgSQL) to reuse the **uid** in the second subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so much easier to think about using `join`s:

```
select wc.*, (wc.uid = ws.uid) as mine
from words_chat wc join
     words_games wg
     on wc.gid = wg.gid join
     words_social ws
     on ws.uid in (wg.player1, player2)
where wc.gid = 100 and
      ws.sid = '1111' and
      ws.social = 10
order by created asc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83e13/10) is the SQL Fiddle.